# SQL : how to find one specific data

Tags: mysql

I need to retrieve the "rarest" animals, this mean that I want to show only animals that appears only one time in my table.

For example :

```
1 Rat
2 Squirrel
3 Bat
4 Rat
5 Bat
6 Raccoon 
7 Armadillo 
8 Hamster
9 Rat
10 Hamster
```

My output will say :

> Squirrel, Raccoon, Armadillo.

My commands start like that :

```
SELECT  breed FROM OtherAnimals;
```

Comment: Do a `group by` on the breed `having` count exactly equal to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use conditional aggregation

```
    select breed 
    from OtherAnimals
    group by breed 
    having count(*)=1
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I would use `DISTINCT` for that :

`SELECT DISTINCT breed FROM OtherAnimals`

More info : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/distinct-optimization.html

Comment: In my case it doesn't change anything, it's more the :  having count(*)=1 , who helps to find one specific data